# How do I print something and then its list?

Tags: python

I've got a txt file of all the countries in the world and what kind of products do they export.

This is what one line looks like without any splitting or stripping (notice `\t` and `\n`):
`[Jamaica\t alumina, bauxite, sugar, rum, coffee, yams, beverages, chemicals, wearing apparel, mineral fuels\n]`

I have to write a program which does that:

```
Angola
[ 'oil,', 'diamonds,', 'refined', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'coffee,', 'sisal,', 'fish,', 'fish', 'products,', 'timber,', 'cotton']

Anguilla
[ 'lobster,', 'fish,', 'livestock,', 'salt,', 'concrete', 'blocks,', 'rum']

Antigua and Barbuda
[ 'petroleum', 'products,', 'bedding,', 'handicrafts,', 'electronic', 'components,', 'transport', 'equipment,', 'food,', 'live', 'animals']

Argentina
[ 'soybeans,', 'petroleum,', 'gas,', 'vehicles,', 'corn,', 'wheat']
```

This is what I've done so far but from now on I don't know how to go forward:

```
import os
file=open("exports.txt",'r')
list=[]

for i in file:
    list.append(i.split(" "))

for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
```

As a result I get a list of every country and what does it export:

```
['Angola\t', 'oil,', 'diamonds,', 'refined', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'coffee,', 'sisal,', 'fish,', 'fish', 'products,', 'timber,', 'cotton\n']
['Anguilla\t', 'lobster,', 'fish,', 'livestock,', 'salt,', 'concrete', 'blocks,', 'rum\n']
['Antigua', 'and', 'Barbuda\t', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'bedding,', 'handicrafts,', 'electronic', 'components,', 'transport', 'equipment,', 'food,', 'live', 'animals\n']
['Argentina\t', 'soybeans,', 'petroleum,', 'gas,', 'vehicles,', 'corn,', 'wheat\n']
```

How do I countinue?
Thanks for help

Comment: `import os` is unnecessary here, unless you're using it in a different part of your code (not shown above). Also, it's a bad idea to name your variables `file` (or `list` or `dict`, etc for that matter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it

```
with open("exports.txt",'r') as infile:
    exports = {}
    for line in infile:
        parts = line.partition('\t')
        exports[parts[0]] = parts[-1].strip().split(', ')

for country, exports in exports.iteritems():
    print country
    print exports
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you're missing a bracket from where you build the list of exports.

Comment: @thegrinner: you're absolutely right. Thanks for the bugreport. Fixed

Comment: Splits the line unnecessarily twice. I would use `key, value = line.split('\t', 1); exports[key] = value`.

Comment: Wow, I've been developing in Python for years and never knew about `<str>.partition(...)`.  Thanks!

Comment: @jdotjdot89: I learned about it fairly recently, too. It's one of those things that isn't readily obvious

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already got the list you mentioned, you can simply do

```
>>> some_list
[['Angola\t', 'oil,', 'diamonds,', 'refined', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'coffee,', 'sisal,', 'fish,', 'fish', 'products,', 'timber,', 'cotton\n'], ['Anguilla\t', 'lobster,', 'fish,', 'livestock,', 'salt,', 'concrete', 'blocks,', 'rum\n'], ['Antigua', 'and', 'Barbuda\t', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'bedding,', 'handicrafts,', 'electronic', 'components,', 'transport', 'equipment,', 'food,', 'live', 'animals\n'], ['Argentina\t', 'soybeans,', 'petroleum,', 'gas,', 'vehicles,', 'corn,', 'wheat\n']]
>>> for row in some_list:
    print row[0]
    print map(str.strip,row[1:])


Angola  
['oil,', 'diamonds,', 'refined', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'coffee,', 'sisal,', 'fish,', 'fish', 'products,', 'timber,', 'cotton\n']
Anguilla    
['lobster,', 'fish,', 'livestock,', 'salt,', 'concrete', 'blocks,', 'rum\n']
Antigua
['and', 'Barbuda\t', 'petroleum', 'products,', 'bedding,', 'handicrafts,', 'electronic', 'components,', 'transport', 'equipment,', 'food,', 'live', 'animals\n']
Argentina   
['soybeans,', 'petroleum,', 'gas,', 'vehicles,', 'corn,', 'wheat\n']
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, but then I get:  United
['Kingdom\t', 'manufactured', 'goods,', 'fuels,', 'chemicals,', 'food,', 'beverages,', 'tobacco\n']

Answer (score 0):

When you're iterating through the list from the file, you can use `list.pop(0)` - this will give you the first element of the list and remove it from the list.

I'd also recommend switching to using the `with` keyword for opening the file, and changing your variable name. So something like:

```
with open("exports.txt",'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

for line in lines: 
    print line.pop(0) #Note that this doesn't actually remove the tab
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice: construct a dict mapping the country to the things it produces, and split each line on the "\t"

```
file=open("exports.txt",'r')
dict = {}

for i in file:
    spl_line = i.split("\t")
    dict[spl_line[0]] = spl_line[1].split(" ")
```