# Using global variables

Tags: python, global-variables

My question is referring to my previous python problem which I was able to solve and make it work perfectly.
[How do I print something and then its list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382293/how-do-i-print-something-and-then-its-list)

Recently, I've been introduced with global variables, but I have no idea how to use them, I've got two functions which I'm not allowed to change:

```
def who_exports(product):
    return products[product]

def what_exports(country):
    return countries[country]
```

I have to write a function called prepare_data() which prepares data and makes all variables and those two functions work. It prepares data for who_exports and what_exports.
It should work like that:

```
who_exports("nickel")
{'Botswana', 'Colombia', 'Cuba'}
```

and then

```
what_exports("Yemen")
{' oil, coffee, fish, liquefied natural gas'}
```

I've been trying and trying and I either get global name "products,countries,country,..." is not defined or keyerror:"nickel".

```
def prepare_data():
    global products
    global product
    global countries
    global country

    countries={}
    products={}
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Don't use them. The number of times they are the right choice is very small.

Comment: Since your previous problem is solved, do you want to accept one of the answers that is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear why you need `country` and `product` as globals, since you can just call `who_exports('nickel')`, specifying the particular `product`.

This is what I'd do for `countries` and `products`, though.

```
def prepare_data():
    countries = {'Yemen' : 'oil, coffee, fish, liquefied natural gas'}
    products = {'nickel' : ['Botswana', 'Colombia', 'Cuba']}
    return countries, products

countries, products = prepare_data()
```

Comment: @user1824179: Are you populating those dictionaries? What exactly are you running to produce the key error?

Comment: @user1824179: I've edited my snippet. Does that work as expected?

Comment: Hello, I think you misunderstood me, could you please have a look at my previous question, I have a list of all countries and their exports..nickel and Yemen was just an example how the function should work

Comment: @user1824179: I realize that you have more data, but I'm not sure what form you currently have it in. Do you have a dictionary like the answer to your previous question suggests? If so, the dictionary `exports` is `countries`, and you'll need to iterate through `countries` to produce `products`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304980/invert-keys-and-values-of-the-original-dictionary for an idea of how, though you'll need to iterate through the lists of products for each country too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of literal dictionaries.